# Embedding a dashboard inside a google chart table

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Following this post: [Embedding a line chart inside a google chart table inside an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239433/embedding-a-line-chart-inside-a-google-chart-table-inside-an-html-page)
I want to get a table that looks like this:
[image]

Only replacing the line chart with a dashboard chart like the following:
[image]

Run the following snippet with my code to see the results I'm getting.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls', 'table', 'charteditor']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var tableData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  tableData.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Chart');
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Test');
  tableData.addRows([
    ['Mike', {
      v: 10000,
      f: '$10,000'
    }, null, '5thFirst'],
    ['Jim', {
      v: 8000,
      f: '$8,000'
    }, null, '5thSecond'],
    ['Alice', {
      v: 12500,
      f: '$12,500'
    }, null, '5thThird'],
    ['Bob', {
      v: 7000,
      f: '$7,000'
    }, null, '5thForth']
  ]);


  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    // table body
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('tbody'), function(tableBody) {
      // table rows
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableBody.rows, function(tableRow, rowIndex) {
        // table cells
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableRow.cells, function(tableCell, cellIndex) {
          // determine if last cell
          if (cellIndex === (2)) {
            // var dashboardDiv = document.createElement('div');
            // dashboardDiv.setAttribute("id", "dashboard_div");
            var dashboardContainer = tableCell.appendChild(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
            //dashboardContainer.className = 'chart';

            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
              'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
              'containerId': 'control_div',
              'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 0,
                'ui': {
                  'chartOptions': {
                    'height': 50,
                    'chartArea': {
                      'width': '75%'
                    },
                    'series': {
                      0: {
                        'targetAxisIndex': 0
                      },
                      1: {
                        'targetAxisIndex': 1
                      }
                    },
                    'vAxes': {
                      0: {
                        'title': 'Weight'
                      },
                      1: {
                        'title': 'smA'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
              'chartType': 'ComboChart',
              'containerId': 'chart_div',
              'options': {
                'legend': {
                  'position': 'bottom',
                  'alignment': 'center',
                  'textStyle': {
                    'fontSize': 12
                  }
                },
                'explorer': {
                  'actions': ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
                  'axis': 'horizontal',
                  'keepInBounds': true
                },
                'hAxis': {
                  'title': 'X'
                },
                'pointSize': 3,
                'series': {
                  0: {
                    'targetAxisIndex': 0
                  },
                  1: {
                    'targetAxisIndex': 1
                  }
                },
                'vAxes': {
                  0: {
                    'title': 'Weight'
                  },
                  1: {
                    'title': 'smA'
                  }
                }
              }
            });

            // build chart data table
            var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartData.addColumn('date', 'timestamp');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'weight');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'smA');
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 0, 1), 1, 123]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 1, 1), 6, 42]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 2, 1), 4, 49]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 3, 1), 23, 486]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 4, 1), 89, 476]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 5, 1), 46, 444]);

            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dashboardContainer);
            dashboard.bind(control, chart);
            dashboard.draw(chartData);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });

  table.draw(tableData, {
    showRowNumber: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.beige-background {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
  <div id="dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div"></div>
          <div id="control_div" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**I want the dashboard to be inserted into every row. What could be the issue?**

Comment: Can you replace `function getData() { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getPlantsData();
}` with some minimal actual sample data for us to reproduce? For pointers see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What was the issue? Can you post an answer?

Comment: I meant I fixed what you said :) changed it to sample data, still don't know the solution

Comment: I see. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason the dashboard only appears in the last row is because there is only one dashboard element.
as it goes through the loop, it appends and moves the dashboard to each cell,
ending up in the last row when the loop is finished.

rather than using an existing dashboard element,
let's add dashboard elements dynamically, one for each row.

here, we use an html template to store the dashboard content.

```
<!-- template: dashboard template -->
<script id="template-dashboard" type="text/html">
  <div id="dashboard-{{Id}}" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart-{{Id}}"></div>
          <div id="control-{{Id}}" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

then add the content to each table cell,
using the row index as the id for each dashboard and control.

```
// insert dashboard html
tableCell.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', renderTemplate('template-dashboard', {
  Id: rowIndex
}));
```

then we can reference the newly created elements using the id...

```
// build dashboard
var dashboardContainer = tableCell.appendChild(document.getElementById('dashboard-' + rowIndex));
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls', 'table', 'charteditor']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var tableData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  tableData.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Chart');
  tableData.addColumn('string', 'Test');
  tableData.addRows([
    ['Mike', {
      v: 10000,
      f: '$10,000'
    }, null, '5thFirst'],
    ['Jim', {
      v: 8000,
      f: '$8,000'
    }, null, '5thSecond'],
    ['Alice', {
      v: 12500,
      f: '$12,500'
    }, null, '5thThird'],
    ['Bob', {
      v: 7000,
      f: '$7,000'
    }, null, '5thForth']
  ]);


  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    // table body
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('tbody'), function(tableBody) {
      // table rows
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableBody.rows, function(tableRow, rowIndex) {
        // table cells
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableRow.cells, function(tableCell, cellIndex) {
          // determine cell
          if (cellIndex === (2)) {
            // insert dashboard html
            tableCell.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', renderTemplate('template-dashboard', {
              Id: rowIndex
            }));

            // build dashboard
            var dashboardContainer = tableCell.appendChild(document.getElementById('dashboard-' + rowIndex));

            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
              'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
              'containerId': 'control-' + rowIndex,
              'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 0,
                'ui': {
                  'chartOptions': {
                    'height': 50,
                    'chartArea': {
                      'width': '75%'
                    },
                    'series': {
                      0: {
                        'targetAxisIndex': 0
                      },
                      1: {
                        'targetAxisIndex': 1
                      }
                    },
                    'vAxes': {
                      0: {
                        'title': 'Weight'
                      },
                      1: {
                        'title': 'smA'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
              'chartType': 'ComboChart',
              'containerId': 'chart-' + rowIndex,
              'options': {
                'legend': {
                  'position': 'bottom',
                  'alignment': 'center',
                  'textStyle': {
                    'fontSize': 12
                  }
                },
                'explorer': {
                  'actions': ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
                  'axis': 'horizontal',
                  'keepInBounds': true
                },
                'hAxis': {
                  'title': 'X'
                },
                'pointSize': 3,
                'series': {
                  0: {
                    'targetAxisIndex': 0
                  },
                  1: {
                    'targetAxisIndex': 1
                  }
                },
                'vAxes': {
                  0: {
                    'title': 'Weight'
                  },
                  1: {
                    'title': 'smA'
                  }
                }
              }
            });

            // build chart data table
            var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartData.addColumn('date', 'timestamp');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'weight');
            chartData.addColumn('number', 'smA');
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 0, 1), 1, 123]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 1, 1), 6, 42]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 2, 1), 4, 49]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 3, 1), 23, 486]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 4, 1), 89, 476]);
            chartData.addRow([new Date(2016, 5, 1), 46, 444]);

            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dashboardContainer);
            dashboard.bind(control, chart);
            dashboard.draw(chartData);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });

  table.draw(tableData, {
    showRowNumber: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  });
}

// render html template
function renderTemplate(templateId, templateValues) {
  var templateText;   // html string to return
  var templateValue;  // html value

  // get template html
  templateText = document.getElementById(templateId).innerHTML;

  // replace place holders with values
  if (templateValues) {
    for (var propHandle in templateValues) {
      if (templateValues.hasOwnProperty(propHandle)) {
        templateValue = '';
        if (templateValues[propHandle] !== null) {
          templateValue = templateValues[propHandle].toString();
        }
        if (templateValue.indexOf('$') > -1) {
          templateValue = templateValue.replace(new RegExp('\\$', 'g'), '$$$');
        }
        if (templateText.indexOf('{{' + propHandle + '}}') > -1) {
          templateText = templateText.replace(new RegExp('{{' + propHandle + '}}', 'g'), templateValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return templateText.trim();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.beige-background {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>

    <!-- template: dashboard template -->
    <script id="template-dashboard" type="text/html">
      <div id="dashboard-{{Id}}" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <table class="columns">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="chart-{{Id}}"></div>
              <div id="control-{{Id}}" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px;"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is coming from the following line:

> `var dashboardContainer = tableCell.appendChild(document.createElement('dashboard_div'));`

What kind of element is **"dashboard_div"**? This creates the following:

> `<dashboard_div></dashboard_div>`

I'm sure that's not what you want because you want to insert the chart in:

> `<div id="dashboard_div">`

And these two things are not the same.

You could probably look at the result by inspecting the HTML using the developer console to see if the chart is really being inserted in the correct HTML tag.

---

#### References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Ok, I changed this line: 
tableCell.appendChild(document.createElement('dashboard_div'));
To this:
tableCell.appendChild(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
And now it is inside the correct cell, but in just the last row and not all rows like the first example, what could be the issue?

Comment: I edited your question for more clarity, feel free to roll back if you think it is different. Now, what is your question ? How to put the same chart in each row?

Comment: Exactly, The final object is to put a different chart each row, but for now, I don't understand why the loop is not doing the same each row as was with the linecharts.

Comment: One thing to remember is that there can only be one element with id="dashboard_div"