# Customize Cells of a Google Table chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I am trying to create the 'Sprint Release' chart shown below, using Google Table chart.

I was able to draw the table with the data, however I am unable to figure out drawing the 'Progress' column. The Progress column shows the number of 'open / in-progress and closed' defects in the form of a Stacked bar chart.

Is it possible to achieve the same with Google charts ? What is the closest we can come up with ??

[image: Sprint Release Chart Expected]

Comment: you could draw an actual bar chart, within the table cell. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64248375/5090771) is an answer that draws a line chart within each row. obviously, you would want to format the bar chart much differently, than the line chart found in the answer. but this should get you started...

Comment: @WhiteHat, yes this is helpful. let me give it a try..